# Ruby multiple regex gsub in one pass, using different capture groups

Tags: regex, ruby

In Ruby, how do I do the following in one pass:

```
text.gsub(/==(.+?)==/){$1.upcase}.gsub(/=(.+?)=/){$1.downcase}
```

If `text = "==aaa== =BBB="`, return value should be `"AAA bbb"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
text.gsub(/(={1,2})(.*?)\1/) { $1.length == 1 ? $2.downcase : $2.upcase}
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/pVBBrv) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qWmtGi/1).

*Details*:

- `(={1,2})` - one or two `=` chars captured into Group 1
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\1` - the same text as captured in Group 1.

If Group 1 holds the `=` value, the replacement is the lowercased Group 2 value, else, it is the uppercased Group 2 value.

Comment: Don't you need (.+?), instead of (.*?) ?

Comment: @Starscream512 I'd rather stick to `.*?` when matching text in between identical delimiters to avoid matching text that is not in between if there are "empty" `==`s.